# ie 10 cross domain ajax request

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-10

I have developed a web application that makes  ajax requests to a web service on a server in a different domain from the server that hosts the web app.

I have configured the web service to do a pre-flight check to set the necessary headers to allow a cross domain request.

In the web app I am using a JQuery client to access the web service. I have set the properties on the Jquery command to allow cross domain access.

$.support.cors = true;

In Chrome this all works fine.  In IE9, however the cross domain behavior is only partially successful.  All get requests work.  But post requests with a content-type of application/json  fail because IE9 refuses to make post requests with any content-type except text/html.  IE9 switches the content-type on the request and the request fails on the server with a 400 bad request.

I had read that with IE10 the cross domain request would work as in Chrome.  But after just testing this, I find that IE10 has the same behavior as IE9.  The browser will not  set the content-type to application/json.   So post requests fail.

Does anyone know whether it is possible in IE10 to do cross domain post requests with other content-types than text/html.  This makes writing web apps that do anything more than display data extremely difficult.

Are there other settings I need to make on the Jquery request?  Or in the service pre-flight?

Answer (score 0):

What does your $.ajax() call look like? You could try adding `data: 'json'` to your JQuery call in order to force the data type to be json. You also shouldn't need to set `$.support.cors = true;`, JQuery should figure this out for you (but its ok to leave it in for now).

Answer (score -1):

I do have the content type param set data: 'json'.
Chrome honors this but IE switches to text/html.  I had read that this was a know issue in IE9 and below but that IE10 would be using the same ajax implementation as Chrome, but this is apparently not the case.

Comment: This should be left as a comment, not an answer.